Cortex-R5 reset encounters instruction prefetch exception
I was trying to reset a Cortex-R5 which is a subsystem in an SoC. The reset signal employed is nRESETm, and the SCTLR.V bit is 0 (i.e. the exception vector table is acquired at 0x0000_0000, a.k.a the on-core TCM address). The instruction at the reset vector (i.e. vector table + 0x0) is modified to ldr pc, [pc, #0x4], which loads instruction address from where the Undefined Instruction exception handler was originally located (as a PoC, the instruction at this address was modified manually to another app's entry point).
After the changes, the exception vector table contains something like this:
0x0000_0000: 0xE59FF004 ; ldr pc, [pc + #0x4]. Was 0xE59FF018, i.e. ldr pc, [pc, #0x18]
0x0000_0004: 0xFFFC01A0 ; target app entry point. Was 0xE59FF018 too.
0x0000_0008: 0xE59FF018
0x0000_000c: 0xE59FF018

Before the changes, the CPU is capable of resetting into the appropriate entry point. However, with the changes, I saw that the CPU bumps into Instruction Fetch exception upon reset (observed through JTAG pausing the CPU).
The instruction at 0xFFFC01A0 is actually the bootloader entry point, so if the PC is properly populated, there should be no problem with the subsequent instructions. Plus, the reset vector originally points to the app entry point, and I would like the reset to start the CPU from the bootloader, so the changes.
Why the changes can lead to a Instruction Fetch exception? Anything I've missed?

The issue is that pc isn't the address of the current instruction; it's the current instruction plus 8 (in ARM state, Thumb is different).  So if the target address is going to be at address 4, then at address 0 you need ldr pc, [pc, #-0x4].

Yep, my understanding about the PC turns out is wrong, which is also the reason that the offsets in the exception vector table looks mis-match to me. Thanks!
